# Se puede convertir un archivo TXT a JSON?? Algun ejemplo de funcion JavaScript. Soy novato

Tags: javascript

Actualmente tengo este formato de un `txt`

```
RODRIGUEZ=Apellido Paterno ,ESQUIVEL= Apellido Materno  ,HECTOR 
MIGUEL=Nombres  ,C RAYON 41=Direccion
```

Y quiero pasarlo a formato `JSON` para que se mas legible. Agradecere cualquier ayuda

Tengo esta funcion donde `archivo.txt` es el archivo que genero y quiero pasarlo a json. No estoy seguro si asi funciona

```
var file_name = 'archivo.txt';

var readline = require('readline');
var fs = require('fs');

var lineReader = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(file_name)
});

var isHeader = false;
var columnNames = [];

function parseLine(line) {
    return line.trim().split('\t')
}

function createRowObject(values) {
    var rowObject = {};

    columnNames.forEach((value,index) => {
        rowObject[value] = values[index];
    });

    return rowObject;
}

var json = {};
json[file_name] = [];

lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
    if(!isHeader) {
        columnNames = parseLine(line);
        isHeader = true;
    } else {
        json[file_name].push(createRowObject(parseLine(line)));
    }
});

lineReader.on('close', function () {
    fs.writeFileSync(file_name + '.json', JSON.stringify(json,null,2));
});
//Termina
```

Comment: ¿Ese archivo TXT es generado bajo un formato? Bienvenido a SOes. Date una vuelta por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Si así es. Saludos

Comment: Nada has intentado, al menos no se ve en tu pregunta, sin embargo, ahí te va el algoritmo: Considerando que ya tienes una clase "Persona", necesitas una Lista<Persona> y luego... Lees todo el archivo TXT, en cada línea leída: separas mediante un `.split(',')` esto te dará un arreglo donde el arreglo[0]  va a ser `RODRIGUEZ=Apellido Paterno `, a esta línea le aplicas otro `.split('=')`, que te dará un segundo arreglo, donde la posición `[0] es RODRIGUEZ` y la posición `[1]` es `Apellido Paterno`, a ésta te sugiero darle un `.trim()` para que evites espacios en blanco. Haces comparaciones...

Comment: Y con éstas comparaciones vas armando tu objeto "Persona", cuando lo tengas completo, lo agregas a lista previamente creada. Finalmente Serializas esa Lista y listo, ahí tienes tu formato completo.

Comment: Olvidé mencionar que estos comentarios vienen desde un punto de vista de C#, en Javascript puro no hay `List<Clase>`por lo que un arreglo de objetos estaría bien, recuerda darle un `.push()` al tema. Buena suerte

Answer (score 1):

Admito que me compliqué un poco para la resolución, pero una alterativa podría ser algo así:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'>
    </body> 
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var openFile = function(event) 
{
    var input = event.target;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function()
    {
        var texto = reader.result;
        var texto_array = texto.split("\r\n");
        var nombre;
        var apellido;
        var edad;
        var i = 0;
        for (var element in texto_array) 
        {
            var json_element;
            if(i%3 == 0)
                nombre = texto_array[element];
            else if(i%3 == 1)
                apellido = texto_array[element];
            else if(i%3 == 2)
            {
                edad = texto_array[element];
                json_element = {"nombre": nombre, "apellido": apellido, "edad": edad};
                console.log(json_element);
            }
            i++;
        }
    };
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
}
</script>
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Fuente de lectura de texto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file)

En tu caso deberías adaptar el split y el i%numero de optar por esta solución.
Saludos.

Comment: Eso es precisamente lo que ando buscando Juanjoo.. Muchas gracias!! Solo una duda pudieras orientarme o explicarme como adaptar el split y el i%numero. Te agradezco mucho!! Tienes alguna pagina para hacerte alguna donacion??

Comment: Hola, en tu caso el split podrías intentar poniendo = es decir que va a separar por igual y el i%numero sería en tu caso la cantidad de campos por 2. En primer lugar podrías hacer el split con =, y con console.log ir evaluando. Igual repito que hay otra forma mas "prolija" de realizar lo mismo, en cuanto tenga tiempo la comento.

Comment: OK OK Muchas gracias por la ayuda Juanjoo Tocino. Te agradezco ya que soy algo novato en este tema.. Saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví de esta manera.. ya lo probé y esta funcionando..

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'>
    </body> 
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

function escapeSpecialChars(jsonString) {
    return jsonString.replace(/\n/g, "\\n")
    .replace(/\r/g, "\\r")
    .replace(/\t/g, "\\t")
    .replace(/\f/g, "\\f");
}

var openFile = function(event) 
{
    var input = event.target;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function()
    {
        var texto = reader.result.replace(new RegExp(',$'), '');
        var texto_array = texto.split(",");

        let elementoSoloValue = null; 
        let jsonINE = "["; 
        texto_array.forEach(function(datoINE, indexElement){ 
            let keyValue = datoINE.split('='); 

            if(keyValue.length > 1){


                if(elementoSoloValue){
                    keyValue[0] = elementoSoloValue + " " + keyValue[0];
                    elementoSoloValue = null; // Reseteamos a null de que ya no hay elemento solo por ahora
                }


                jsonINE +='{' +
                    '"name": "' + keyValue[1] + '", ' +
                    '"value": "' + keyValue[0] + '", ' +
                    '"sinEspaco": "' + (keyValue[1]).replace(new RegExp(' ', 'g'), '') + '"' +
                '}';

                // Si no es el último elemento del arreglo texto_array, le agregamos una coma al string, porque se va a agregar otro elemento,
                // Pero si es esl último ya no le pongamos coma
                if(indexElement + 1 < texto_array.length){
                    jsonINE += ',';
                }
            }else{

                elementoSoloValue = keyValue[0];
            }
        });
        jsonINE += ']'; //Cerramos el arreglo

        jsonINE = escapeSpecialChars(jsonINE); // Escapamos los caracteres especiales
        var ine = JSON.parse(jsonINE); // Convertimos el string a JSON
        console.log('INE EN FORMATO JSON:');
        console.log(ine);


    };
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
}
</script>
```